# SQL Warning with Spring boot and Sybase

Tags: java, sql, spring, spring-boot, sybase

I am getting a lot of SQL Warning in the logs with the spring boot and sybase.

```
o.h.engine.jdbc.spi.SqlExceptionHelper   : [] SQL Warning Code: 0, SQLState: 010SK 
o.h.engine.jdbc.spi.SqlExceptionHelper   : [] 010SK: Database cannot set connection option SET_READONLY_TRUE. 
  
    
o.h.engine.jdbc.spi.SqlExceptionHelper   : [] 010SK: Database cannot set connection option SET_READONLY_FALSE.
```

Could anyone explain the reason behind this?

Comment: which Sybase db product (ASE? IQ? SQLAnywhere? Advantage?) and version?  I'm not familiar with spring boot so ... could you explain what 'SET_READONLY_FALSE' is supposed to do, what you're trying to set it to, and what operation are you looking to perform that requires this setting? [I'm guessing the Sybase db product you're connecting to either does not support this particular setting or is sending a response the app doesn't know how to process, but need more details to a) know for sure and b) come up with a solution to what you're trying to accomplish)

Comment: i am also facing same issue. did you find the solution for this issue?

Comment: I am not able to find any sol.

Answer (score 1):

**Solution 1:**

java.sql.Connection has a setReadOnly(boolean) method that is meant to notify the database of the type of result set being requested in order to perform any optimizations. However Sybase ASE doesn't require any optimizations, therefore setReadOnly() produces a SQLWarning.

In order to suppress the message you'll need to update the spt_mda table in the MASTER database.

```
update spt_mda set querytype = 4, set query = '0'
where mdinfo = 'SET_READONLY_FALSE'
```

and

```
update spt_mda set querytype = 4, set query = '0'
where mdinfo = 'SET_READONLY_TRUE'
```

These two entries (they are the only ones) are set to a querytype of 3 by default, which means "not supported", which explains the SQLWarning.

Changing them to a 4 (meaning boolean values) with a query type of "0" basically causes the JDBC Driver to return false without the warning..

**Solution 2:**

You might turn off/on on logging for specific part of hibernate logging modules, these are different configurations:

```
 # Hibernate logging
# Log everything (a lot of information, but very useful for troubleshooting)
log4j.logger.org.hibernate=FATAL
# Log all SQL DML statements as they are executed
log4j.logger.org.hibernate.SQL=INHERITED
# Log all JDBC parameters
log4j.logger.org.hibernate.type=INHERITED
# Log all SQL DDL statements as they are executed
log4j.logger.org.hibernate.tool.hbm2ddl=INHERITED
# Log the state of all entities (max 20 entities) associated with the session at flush time
log4j.logger.org.hibernate.pretty=INHERITED
# Log all second-level cache activity
log4j.logger.org.hibernate.cache=INHERITED
# Log all OSCache activity - used by Hibernate
log4j.logger.com.opensymphony.oscache=INHERITED
# Log transaction related activity
log4j.logger.org.hibernate.transaction=INHERITED
# Log all JDBC resource acquisition
log4j.logger.org.hibernate.jdbc=INHERITED
# Log all JAAS authorization requests
log4j.logger.org.hibernate.secure=INHERITED
```

Possible values:

```
OFF     
FATAL   
ERROR   
WARN    
INFO    
DEBUG   
TRACE   
ALL
```

Comment: Don't forget to use master as user: 

use matser;